# Why can't I get to my router's admin & settings using Google Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, settings, router

I'm trying to get to my router's admin console using Google Chrome but when I type the URL for it Chrome redirects to this page:
[image: The image says 404 Not Found and the redirected URL is: ".../cgi-bin/check_hijack.html"]

The image says "404 Not Found" and the redirected URL is: ".../cgi-bin/check_hijack.html"

I've tried clearing all my history attached to a 192.168.X.X URL, deleting all my saved passwords for those admin pages and IP addresses but none has worked so far.

I'm using a Mac and the interesting part is I can get to my router's admin console via Safari or Firefox but Google Chrome just won't work.

Any ideas?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which router do you have?

- Try to use google chrome in anonymous window.
- You can check if same protocol is used in the browsers ( it's the part in front of visible url - it is hidden in chrome (http, https, .... You can see it when you cpy-paste the url)

Comment: Tried opening the URL in "Incognito" mode and it worked. Wonder why it doesn't on a "non-private" window.

Comment: i have a current generation netgear c6300 docsis3 modem and accessing http://192.168.0.1/ from regular and incognito mode, not sure what anoymous mode is, both produce a `This page isn’t working 192.168.0.1 sent an invalid response. ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE`.  I switch to edge and its fine.  Seems really odd that chrome doesn't support talking to ones broadband router admin page since that would be such a common home user task.